Wix 3.14 to 4.0.6 .wixproj file
I'm trying to figure out a step in the upgrade process from 3.14 with the wix toolset installed on my machine to using Wix 4.0.6 and install wix with dotnet tools to a custom location.
With Wix 3.14, the build references the wix/3.x wix.targets file in my .wixproj, to check it exists. Which is fine for 3.14, but on 4.0.6, I don't have those files. Which I believe is intended since it is now handled by the SDK. The block of code below is what was used on 3.14
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets" Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets') " />
  <Target Name="EnsureWixToolsetInstalled" Condition=" '$(WixTargetsImported)' != 'true' ">
    <Error Text="The WiX Toolset v3.14 (or newer) build tools must be installed to build this project. To download the WiX Toolset, see http://wixtoolset.org/releases/" />
  </Target>

My question is, what replaces this wix check for 4.0.6? I tried pointing it to the path I told dotnet tools to install wix 4.0.6 (the wix.exe), but it that didn't work or specifying a specific x86 or x64 variant in the other directories. I checked the directories and there isn't a wix.targets file I can swap with.
I checked the documentation best I could, but couldn't find an answer. Does anyone know what to do in this instance?
EnsureWixToolsetInstalled if removed wont let it build since its required.
Any thoughts on the matter would be appreciated, thank you and have a good day :)
